# Erro Android: Apache HttpClient does not exist

Tags: android, api, android-studio

Agora é obrigatorio pela google ter no código essa [atualização](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk) onde se altera a versão do `targetSdkVersion`para aplicar API's mais recentes nos aplicativos.

Alterei os valores da `SdkVersion` para 26 como foi recomendado pela google play.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'    
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }
```

Porém ao realizar a build, o aplicativo me retorna o erro sobre o pacote `org.apache.http` não poder ser econtrado juntamente com outras propriedades do arquivo como`classes` e `variáveis`.

```
Error:(19, 23) error: package org.apache.http does not exist
Error:(20, 23) error: package org.apache.http does not exist    
Error:(230, 13) error: cannot find symbol class HttpEntity
Error:(231, 29) error: cannot find symbol variable EntityUtils
```

Eu estou esquecendo de colocar alguma informação no meu código? Pois a unica coisa que alterei foi o número das `SdkVersion`. Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Caro hunterxhunter, o jar do org.apache esta no projeto? Tem certeza que não o removeu por acidente? Só estou perguntando para podermos ter um parametro para conseguir te ajudar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ta sim.